# How to define table indexing with ascending/descending columns, nulls last using Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

With native query

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index
    ON public.table USING btree
    (column1 ASC NULLS LAST, column2 ASC NULLS LAST);
```

How to define similar indexing with Liquibase?

```
<createIndex tableName="table" indexName="ACT_IDX_table" unique="true">
     <column name="column1" />
     <column name="column2" />
</createIndex>
```

DB - Postgres

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, you are not able to set NULLs last in liquibase. You can of course always use the  tags to write exactly what you need.

```
<sql>
   CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index
   ON public.table USING btree
   (column1 ASC NULLS LAST, column2 ASC NULLS LAST); 
</sql>
```